# Bundling not working in Sitecore MVC

Tags: bundling

I'm trying to implement bundling in Sitecore 8.2 and followed all the steps in this [document](https://jockstothecore.com/bundling-with-sitecore-mvc/).

The breakpoint is hit for the `RegisterBundles` method, but the assets are not rendered on page.

In the layout, it only renders this:

```
<link href="/bundles/css?v=" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

The processor specified in the document did not work for me. The breakpoint wasn't being hit. I changed it to this:

**patch.config**

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
<sitecore>
   <pipelines>
      <initialize>
         <processor patch:before="processor[@type='Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Loader.ShowVersion, Sitecore.Kernel']"
            type="MyProject.Web.Pipelines.RegisterPlatformBundles, MyProject" />
      </initialize>
   </pipelines>
</sitecore>
</configuration>
```

**RegisterPlatformBundles.cs**

```
private void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            /// Bundled CSS 
            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/css").Include(
                    "~/Assets/css/main.css?v=202001236",
                    "~/Assets/css/dev.css?v=202001231"
                ));            
        }
```

**Layout.cshtml**

```
<head>
   @Styles.Render("~/bundles/css")
</head>
```

**UPDATE:**
@Mahendra's suggestion worked for me. 
I removed the versions from the css references.
Also, to fix the incorrect image/font paths, I changed the `RegisterBundles` method to this:

```
private void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
   /// Bundled CSS 
   bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/css")
            .Include("~/Assets/css/main.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform())
            .Include("~/Assets/css/dev.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform()));            
}
```

Comment: did you try by adding ~ i.e ~/bundles/css? also, try by removing the query from the include section

Comment: @MahendraShekhawat. In the Layout.cshtml, that is how I added. Are you referring to something else?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion here, I mean here is ~//, a double slash in layout. are you getting any 404 error for the link? try to open <link href="/bundles/css?v=" rel="stylesheet"/> (href) in new tab

Comment: Removing the version worked. It now loads as `<link href="/bundles/css?v=blNztwxsF5QM3OLfN6fFdLya8YpG5qMfrbHhfcIUFP81" rel="stylesheet"/>`. But how do I add the versions for a particular file here.

Comment: glad it works, `StyleBundle` class required a physical file and do not accept any query string. updated the same in the answer.

Answer (score 5):

I just had this happen, the issue is that Sitecore is picking on the bundling URL. Need to add your `/bundles/css` to the `IgnoreUrlPrefixes` setting

```
<setting name="IgnoreUrlPrefixes" value="/sitecore/default.aspx|/trace.axd|/webresource.axd|/sitecore/shell/Controls/Rich Text Editor/Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx|/sitecore/shell/applications/content manager/telerik.web.ui.dialoghandler.aspx|/sitecore/shell/Controls/Rich Text Editor/Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd|/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd|/sitecore/admin/upgrade/|/layouts/testing|/sitecore/service/xdb/disabled.aspx?|/bundles/css" />
```

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET MVC API includes `StyleBundle` class that does CSS minification and bundling. If it is not working, then there a few things which we need to check -

- Make sure all files exists as a physical file, a virtual path will not work since it is not created yet
- `Styles.Render` have a proper path in the layout
- Make sure render link (virtual path) is not throwing any error, if it is then there may be some error in code.
- Remove any version query from the file path

you can easily check the all included files by enabling and disabling the Bundling and minification by setting the value of the debug attribute `debug="true"` in the compilation element in the Web.config file.

Comment: Please advice how to add a version to a particular file (either css/jss)

Comment: ?v=* is used to makes sure you are getting the latest version of the CSS or js file from the server in a link tag and not a cached copy. Since StyleBundle runs server-side and includes files as physical locations, you can't get a file with a version by the query string. All you need to add the version in the file name such as "main_202001236.css".

Comment: Where to add `?v=*` is unclear. `Main_2020.css` will make the server look for a file with that name. right, whereas the file present is main.css. Could you please clearly how to add a particular file with the latest version.

Comment: ?v=* will only work in <link> tag. yes, the server will look for the file name. now if the main.css file is there then it will be only and latest file there because OS will not allow the multiple files with the same name.

Comment: Your suggestion did not work. The actual file name is main.css. In the method, i changed it to main_2020.css & now it doesn't load. Is that what you suggested.

Comment: All right, we are confused here. Let me know the requirement of adding a version for the file in the code if there is only one main.css file and from where are you getting the version number 202001236?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103841/discussion-between-qwerty-and-mahendra-shekhawat).